# Evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin t}{a^2+k^2t^2}\, dt$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I need to compute
$$ \int_\gamma \frac{dx}{x^2+y^2+z^2},$$
where $\gamma$ is the first turn of the helix $\gamma(t) = (a\cos t, a\sin t, kt),$ that is, $t \in [0, 2\pi].$ I don't see any option other than using the definition, which yields
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \left\langle \left(\frac{1}{a^2\cos^2 t+a^2\sin^2 t+k^2t^2}, 0, 0 \right), \left(-a\sin t, a \cos t, k \right) \right\rangle \,dt = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{-a\sin t}{a^2+k^2t^2}\,dt.$$
But I don't know how to compute this integral. This exercise is supposed to be analytically solvable.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Integration by Parts doesn't work?

Comment: Try partial fraction decomposition and look for exponential integral.

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition plus change of variable to get sine and cosine integrals

Comment: When they say analytically solvable, do they mean in terms of elementary functions or any special functions?

Comment: I guess the mistake lies in the interpretation of the integral: it should not be with respect to $dx$ or $dt$ but with respect to the element of length $ds=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yeah, I think that's plausible.